# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Movies & TV breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 13         23
Users destroyed                                  44          0
Users deleted                                     5          0
Users contacted                                  33          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           415      2,046
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              123        549
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         45      1,259
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               38        635
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                97      1,921
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              235      2,307
Tags merged                                      45          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            14          0
Tag synonyms created                             14          0
Questions unprotected                             2          1
Questions reopened                               58         12
Questions protected                              28         31
Questions migrated                               65          1
Questions merged                                  8          0
Questions flagged⁴                               27        909
Questions closed                              5,306        507
Question flags handled⁴                         380        556
Posts unlocked                                    5         14
Posts undeleted                                  41         63
Posts locked                                  4,699        113
Posts deleted⁵                                4,523      1,405
Posts bumped                                      0        592
Escalations to the CM team                        4          0
Comments undeleted                               18          0
Comments flagged                                 55      1,045
Comments deleted⁶                             2,454      1,490
Comment flags handled                           867        233
Answers flagged                                  35        918
Answer flags handled                            709        244
All comments on a post moved to chat             12          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Happy New Year Shog