# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Movies & TV over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                   8         24
Users destroyed³                                  65          0
Users deleted                                      7          0
Users contacted                                   17          0
User suspensions lifted early                      1          0
User banned from review                            1          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue            587      2,230
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                80        350
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         146      1,072
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue               150        442
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                315      1,703
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue               228      1,833
Tags merged                                       27          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              3          0
Tag synonyms created                               3          0
Revisions redacted                                 1          0
Questions unprotected                              1          3
Questions reopened                                60         16
Questions protected                               34         32
Questions migrated                                13          0
Questions merged                                   3          0
Questions flagged⁵                                27        771
Questions closed                                 692        362
Question flags handled⁵                          375        421
Posts unlocked                                     0          1
Posts undeleted                                    9         49
Posts locked                                       3        105
Posts deleted⁶                                   592      1,176
Posts bumped                                       0        311
Escalations to the Community Manager team          3          0
Comments undeleted                                24          0
Comments flagged                                  52        861
Comments deleted⁷                              1,999      1,301
Comment flags handled                            611        301
Bounties canceled                                  1          0
Answers flagged                                   49        899
Answer flags handled                             674        286
All comments on a post moved to chat              36          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Happy New Year.....!!!!

Comment: wow, from 5,306 questions closed by mods to 692

Comment: I wonder if you can *identify* the reason there, @dforck...